# Checkbox problems inside jQuery dialog and Repeater

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

So I've been basically beating my head against the wall on this for a while now.  Excuse me if I throw up too much code here, don't know a better way to explain it.  I've got a Repeater with an ItemTemplate of:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div id='FileFrame<%#Eval("Id")%>' class="view">
        <userControl:ConfigFiles ID=<%#Eval("Id")%> runat="server" />
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Some jQuery that sets up the dialog box for the div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".view").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: "Configuration Files",
            buttons: {},
            height: 600,
            width: 800,
            open: function (type, data) { $(this).parent().appendTo("form"); }
        });
    });
```

and some more jQuery that opens the dialog.

```
$("#FileFrame"+ConfigId).dialog('open');
```

Now the User Control has a bunch of checkboxes inside of it inside other repeaters along with a "Download Checked Boxes" button.  The problem is that when I go through debugging and click the button, none of the checkboxes are ever read as checked unless I initially set the Checked="true" on the aspx page.

Here's the a snippet from the code behind where it's failing to do what I thought it should do.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in FilesRepeater.Items)
    {
        CheckBox box = item.FindControl("DownloadFileCheckBox") as CheckBox;
        if (box.Checked) //<-- always false unless I set it to true in aspx,
                         //    then it's always true
            {/*do work here*/}
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're missing a closing `%>` on your first `Eval()`

Comment: Thank you, I fixed some other small errors that I made while typing as well.  All of the jQuery works, it opens the dialog and everything.  It's just a question of why the checkboxes aren't being "checked"

Comment: Check what the value of Request.Form[box.UniqueID] is - depending on when you're checking the values, the CheckBox control might not have been updated yet in the ASP.NET Page LifeCycle

Comment: I've had problems like this before. Page_Load will fire, clearing those checkboxes, making your event have unchecked boxes. What is your PageLoad event doing?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it's not doing anything with the checkboxes, just doing some work mostly with the associated Master Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm not 100% sure what exactly happened (which is scary) but the code now works.  My intuition says that something, somewhere, was wrong with a piece of JavaScript and causing the browser to just abandon the following JS.  Bottom-line is that the solution that I posted in the question does work.

I think the main problem was that there was a JS function that I was calling that wasn't being loaded or wasn't within the scope of where the call was being made.  If I find out more I'll be sure to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem ( postback doesn't populate control values) sometime back. The problem was generated dialog was outside the form tag.

Use

```
$("#FileFrame"+ConfigId).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
```

or similar code to move the dialog code inside of form

Hope this will help.

Comment: Already have this when I create the dialog.

    open: function (type, data) { $(this).parent().appendTo("form");

Comment: Did you check the generated html markup to see where exactly the dialog html is located (inside the form tag or outside)? Just an idea, because according to the code, it should work.